# how to add a vertical accolade graphically

Tags: pdftex, moderncv, cv, annotations

I have a Resume (CV) where I'd need to add an vertical note along a half square or accolade to regroup some of the Orange boxes vertically, like on the left part in pink I've drawn manually there [image: Manual draw]

The original latex is the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\geometry{  a4paper, top=20mm,bottom=10mm }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{Surname}{Name}
\title{Ingénieur}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{4 parici}{05800 Parla}

\newtcolorbox{mybox3}[1][]
{ fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,title={#1},    
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacktitle=yellow!50!red,
  coltitle=red!25!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

% Changer les tirets des items par défaut en cercle bleu
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 

\section{Experience}

  \begin{mybox3}[{05/16 - 07/16 \hfill Ingenieur  \hfill Company1}]
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Maintenance d'un système existant d'un client serveur pour le pilotage de benchmarks de carte mères à distance
                \item Développement de nouveaux gestionnaires de benchmarks
                \item compétences hardwares requises
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}

  \begin{mybox3}[{05/15 - 04/16 \hfill Ingenieur  \hfill Company2}]
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Au sein de l'équipe tralala, j'ai parcitipé aux développements pour porter et intégrer les différentes briques middleware créées par les autres équipes 
                \item Nous avons architecturé le projet pour que le logiciel puisse tourner sur les 2 cibles (windows et Qnx) et pour intégrer les options demandées 
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}

  \begin{mybox3}[{09/14 - 04/15 \hfill Responsable projet  \hfill Company3}]
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Mise en place de l'étude d'un projet de système embarqué utilisant un élément radioactif pour la mesure de plomb présent dans les peintures
                \item Spécifications et accompagnement technique du client
                \item participer à l'étude électronique notamment dans la mise en place de certains drivers et composants hardwares
                \item {'Architectures et developpements des logiciels embarqués': 'client, serveurs, services distants, sécurité'}
                \item J'ai effectué la mise en place d'une architecture logicielle de production industrielle au travers de machines virtuelles afin de conserver un environement stable et reproductible
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}


\section{Langues}
\cvitemwithcomment{Anglais}{lu,écrit et parlé}{Courant et technique}
\cvitemwithcomment{Espagnol}{Scolaire}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Italien}{Scolaire}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `tikz`, this could help you :
First : use enhanced skins on tcolorbox.
remember as option to save the position.
Then You can draw the arrow.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\geometry{  a4paper, top=20mm,bottom=10mm }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{Surname}{Name}
\title{Ingénieur}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{4 parici}{05800 Parla}

\newtcolorbox{mybox3}[2][]
{enhanced,fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,title={#2},
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacktitle=yellow!50!red,
  coltitle=red!25!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries, #1}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

% Changer les tirets des items par défaut en cercle bleu
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize\color{blue}{$\circ$}} 

\section{Experience}

\begin{mybox3}[]{05/16 - 07/16 \hfill Ingenieur  \hfill Company1}
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Maintenance d'un système existant d'un client serveur pour le pilotage de benchmarks de carte mères à distance
                \item Développement de nouveaux gestionnaires de benchmarks
                \item compétences hardwares requises
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}

  \begin{mybox3}[remember as=A]{05/15 - 04/16 \hfill Ingenieur  \hfill Company2}
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Au sein de l'équipe tralala, j'ai parcitipé aux développements pour porter et intégrer les différentes briques middleware créées par les autres équipes 
                \item Nous avons architecturé le projet pour que le logiciel puisse tourner sur les 2 cibles (windows et Qnx) et pour intégrer les options demandées 
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}

  \begin{mybox3}[remember as=B]{09/14 - 04/15 \hfill Responsable projet  \hfill Company3}
        \begin{itemize}
       %% Génerer les tags des technos utilisées avec une couleur aléatoire parmis une liste

                \item Mise en place de l'étude d'un projet de système embarqué utilisant un élément radioactif pour la mesure de plomb présent dans les peintures
                \item Spécifications et accompagnement technique du client
                \item participer à l'étude électronique notamment dans la mise en place de certains drivers et composants hardwares
                \item {'Architectures et developpements des logiciels embarqués': 'client, serveurs, services distants, sécurité'}
                \item J'ai effectué la mise en place d'une architecture logicielle de production industrielle au travers de machines virtuelles afin de conserver un environement stable et reproductible
        \end{itemize}       
  \end{mybox3}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[-] (A.north west) to[bend right] node[above] {COUCOU} (B.south west);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A.north west) + (-5mm,0)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(B.south west) + (-5mm,0)$);
    \draw[red] (A.north west) -- (C) --
    node[above, rotate=90, ] {TOTO}
    (D) -- (B.south west);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\section{Langues}
\cvitemwithcomment{Anglais}{lu,écrit et parlé}{Courant et technique}
\cvitemwithcomment{Espagnol}{Scolaire}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Italien}{Scolaire}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good. I could have the vertical text anyway even by adding  the {COUCOU} (error) to the line or \node[draw,rotate=90] at (0,5) {Coucou} (is within a box and at the right instead)

Comment: addendum to my previous comment: \draw[red,rotate=90] (A.north west) -- (C) -- (D) -- (B.south west)node[above]{COUCOU}  ;  is also horizontal & misplaced (should be vertical and centered on the line)

Comment: @dlewin see my edits